# How to limit Sublime Text snippet to parent scope?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is it possible to limit a Sublime Text snippet to a specific scope while excluding its children? In my case, I would like the snippet to work for `text.html` but exclude all child scopes such as `text.html.markdown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude scopes in selectors using the `-` symbol, but you need to exclude each one explicitly, there is no wildcard like `*`. So, for example, to exclude Markdown you could write:

```xml
<scope>text.html -text.html.markdown</scope>
```